# How height is calculated in device emulator of chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I open a website and want to see how would it look like on my smartphone. Since my device name is not listed I select `Responsive` in device name dropdown. Resolution of my device is `720x1440` when I fill these value zoom automatically get reduced to `35%`. And when I change zoom to `100%` the value of height gets changed automatically leaving width same. My question is how this value of height is calculated(if width is 720,how height gets evaluated to `532` and can I change zoom percentage keeping both width and height same?

It can be reproduced on chrome on any website.